# PHP Update class (OO)

Tags: php, oop, class

I have written a PHP OO class which will update 4 fields of a certain row in a table. For now the row is decided by a constant (user with name 'jip')

I have corrected the query in a previous post here, so i'm pretty sure the query itself is fine. So, there must be some sort of error within the class itself. Probaply the vars don't reach the query somehow. I have been looking for hours, but can't find the problem. I have linked both files of the class, since i downt know where the error is, the values just don't show up in the database. If anyone would like to check them, (s)he'd make my entire week! SO here is the link and i hope someone is willing to help :)

UpdateForm.php: http://pastebin.com/dUaZPrn6
Update.class.php: http://pastebin.com/6mnL4DzE

Comment: noone is downloading your code. put it in a pastebin, then maybe we will look at it....

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post the relevant code here so others can benefit from the question too (and SO users are generally not keen on downloading files)

Comment: What's the error? Or are the values just not showing up in the database?

Comment: the values are not showing in the database. There's no error (sorry if that wasnet clear)

Comment: Please try to debug your code next time and ask a more concrete question. We're not debuggers.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $variable)` with

```
$conn->real_escape_string($variable);
```

For example,

```
$conn->real_escape_string($this->Lengte_update);
```

You're using the object-oriented style, so you can't use the procedural escape function. See the docs on [mysqli::real_escape_string](https://www.php.net/mysqli_real_escape_string).

Edit:

The query isn't being executed. You assign the query to $query, but you need to call

```
$conn->query($query);
```

For anything to happen in the database.

Comment: Nothing changes: no errors but no values in the database either. I guess the problem happens earlier on?

Comment: Actually, I don't see the query being executed anywhere. You assign the query to a variable, but it's never prepared and executed (or just executed, using mysqli::query).

Comment: It's the first time i'm using an UPDATE query (i only started php a few months ago) so i might be missing something here, but the class is being executed when the user presses on a submit button on another page with a small form. Is this what you mean?

Comment: I mean, after you've done all of your error checking, before `header("Location: ...");`, you need to call $conn->query($query) so that it's sent to the database. Right now, you're just assigning the UPDATE query to a variable, but the variable isn't used for anything.

Comment: That's probaply the solution indeed! It's after midnight here now and i gotta get out early, so i'll try that tomorrow. i'll be sure to reply.